# I am unable to clear the text area fields after performing the onclick function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clear the textarea field after performing an onclick event, but I am unsure where I am going wrong. I have also looked at a few Stack Overflow questions, but I am still struggling to solve my problem.

I loading my js script like this

```
 <script src="/client.js" defer></script>
```

my html

```
<textarea class="form-control emojionearea-form-control" id="messageInput" rows="1" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>

<div onclick="HandleSentMessage()" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon send-icon rounded-circle text-light mb-1" role="button"></div>
```

my client.js

```
let HandleSentMessage = ()=>{
    console.log("clicked")
    ...others code
    if (Inputmessage.length >1) {
   
    container.appendChild(message);
    message.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' });
    let text = document.getElementById('messageInput'); 
    text.value = "";
           
    } else {
    console.log("Container element not found");
    }
```

you can see a new message element appended after perform on click but the textarea value not clearing
[image]

Comment: First i would check if you have the correct element by `console.log(text)` after `let text = document.getElementById('messageInput'); ` Also are you sure `Inputmessage.length >1` is true?

Comment: when I console.log I can see the value is empty for text but it's not clearing from my frontend index.html

Comment: it was not what i asked, I asked if `text` represent the correct element. When you console.log(text) you should be above to hover the consoled element and it should display it on the html page. remember that if you have multiple elements with the same id, then it's not working

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.